# Show a component after some delay inside return function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, return, settimeout

I'm trying to render a new component after some delay. My approach was this

```
if (success) {
    return
    <span className="small_font white_color border padding_5px horiz_center"
        style={{ marginTop: '-5px' }}>Amount changed</span>
    setTimeout(<Retransfer reqUserId={reqUserId} changeAccountLevel={changeAccountLevel} />, 2000);
} else {
    return addFriend;
}
```

So inside a if statement i'm trying to display

```
<span className="small_font white_color border padding_5px horiz_center"
                      style={{marginTop: '-5px'}}>Amount changed</span>
```

part first and after some delay dispay

```
<Retransfer reqUserId={reqUserId} changeAccountLevel={changeAccountLevel}/>
```

this component. But my approach does not seem to work.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is have a flag in the state that tells whether to show or unshow the Retransfer component . like this

```
state = {
    isVisibleRetransfer: false,
}
componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
            isVisibleRetransfer: true
        })
    }, 2000)
}
```

And in your render

```
if (success) {
    return
    <span className="small_font white_color border padding_5px horiz_center"
        style={{ marginTop: '-5px' }}>Amount changed</span>

    { this.state.isVisibleRetransfer && <Retransfer reqUserId={reqUserId} changeAccountLevel={changeAccountLevel} /> }
} else {
    return addFriend;

}
```

It's not  possible  the way you are doing it

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying will not work, because the function of [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) will get called after specified time and it will not return anything.

Possible Solution is, use a state value inside `Retransfer` and render the content after 2sec or you can maintain that state inside parent component also.

Like this:

```
if (success) {
    return (
        <div>
            <span className="small_font white_color border padding_5px horiz_center"
              style={{marginTop: '-5px'}}>Amount changed
            </span>
            <Retransfer reqUserId={reqUserId} changeAccountLevel={changeAccountLevel}/>
        <div>
    )

} else {
    return addFriend;
}
```

Inside `Retransfer` component:

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        isRenderComp: false,
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        this.seState({ isRenderComp: true })
    }, 2000);
}

render(){
    if(!this.state.isRenderComp)
        return null;
    return(
        ....
    )
}
```

Other issues are:

1- Alone return will be treated as return; [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi), so either use `()` or put the `span` in the same line.

2- You are returning 2 elements inside success block, so wrap the content by a `div`.

Comment: facing any issue?

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` takes two argument, First the function or expression which need to be executed after fixed time passed in second argument.

Thats why it is not working [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

For this to work you can have component which change state of showing Retransfer after fix time.

```
state = {
    isVisibleRetransfer: false,
}
componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
            isVisibleRetransfer: true
        })
    }, 2000)
}
```

And in render

```
if (success) {
    return
    <span className="small_font white_color border padding_5px horiz_center"
        style={{ marginTop: '-5px' }}>Amount changed</span>

    { this.state.isVisibleRetransfer && <Retransfer reqUserId={reqUserId} changeAccountLevel={changeAccountLevel} /> }
} else {
    return addFriend;

}
```